# how to connect to the iota EVM smart contract testnet with metamask?

Tags: iota-network

i d like to test the emerging decentralized apps, decentralized autonomous organizations, digital identity, and non fungible tokens on the iota network from my phone by signing transactions with metamask. how does it have to be configured?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect using the rpc endpoint of ran using `wasp-cli`.

Take a look at the [wiki](https://wiki.iota.org/smart-contracts/guide/evm/tooling#metamask).
Also, shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbUGX-9BTSo&list=PLMbc46iGTB_SCQ-Ut_c8__ssMDFUusVBJ&index=3&ab_channel=IOTAFoundation).